# AWS PHP SDK - Assuming role from different account gives "Error in retrieving assume role credentials."

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, credentials

I have AWS Account 1 with the following role ARN:

```
arn:aws:iam::534953367916:role/role3
```

and the following trust policy for the role (in which I have entered Account 2 user ARN as principal):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::201255186948:user/testuser"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "1234"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In Account 2 I have created access key and secret for "testuser" and I use them in PHP SDK code:

```
  $provider = CredentialProvider::assumeRole([
                'client' => new StsClient([
                    'region' => "us-east-1",
                    'version' => "2011-06-15",
                    'credentials' => [
                        "key" => "AKIAS5W56OICHSKXFKYP", // testuser access key and secret
                        "secret" => "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",
                    ]
                ]),
                'assume_role_params' => [
                    'RoleArn' => "arn:aws:iam::534953367916:role/role3",
                    'RoleSessionName' => 'my-custom-app',
                    'ExternalId' => "1234"
                ],
            ]);

            $s3Client = new S3Client([
                'region' => "us-east-1",
                'version' => "2006-03-01",
                'credentials' => $provider
            ]);
            $adapter = new \League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter($s3Client, $bucket);
            $contents = $adapter->listContents("", true);

            foreach ($contents as $content) {
                
            }
```

I receive error on the "foreach":

```
Error in retrieving assume role credentials.
```

After more debugging I get the internal error:

```
Sender AccessDenied User: arn:aws:iam::201255186948:user/testuser is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::534953367916:role/role3
```

The role has AmazonS3FullAccess permission.

Comment: Does your user have a policy attached that allows the assume role? If you assume cross account you need the permission both on the source principal and on the target resource.

Comment: I think that it doesn't have a policy. I haven't done anything specific to Account 2

Comment: Then you need to attach such a policy to allow the assume role.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Add an answer if you want to be accepted. 
My scenario is that I want users to share their AWS resources with my application (without giving me access keys and secrets) and I though that I can fully automate it, but it seems that I have to add every user role ARN to my user policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross account `assume-role`s *(and any action in general)* you need the permission for the `AssumeRole` call both on the target role *(or resource in general)* in its trust relationship *(resource policy in general)* **and** on the source principal performing the action.

See e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic-cross-account.html